# How to search html file for simple string? 

Tags: php, web-scraping

[Consider this link from Amazon.](http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B00519RW1U/)

If you notice, each seller has this block (similar, at least):

```
<a href="http://www.amazon.com/shops/AN8LN2YPKS7DF/ref=olp_merch_name_2">
<img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41UQmT7-XyL.jpg" width="120" alt="DataVision Computer Video" height="30" border="0" />
</a> //and other junk
```

I want to search this page for `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41UQmT7-XyL.jpg`, which is the seller image (which I already have the link for).  I just want to know if the search produced results, or not.  I don't even need to know more than that.  Is this possible?  How can I do it using PHP?

Comment: Use a HTML parser. See [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

Comment: Do you want to search local files or online one?

Comment: @David: I want to search it while it's online.

Comment: @Pekka: I don't want to parse the html.  I want to download the html on the server and see if a simple string is present.  Parsing seems like overkill.

Comment: @Shorty ah, fair enough.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do here - if it's searching Amazon programmatically, [you may find this interesting...](http://scripts.incutio.com/amazon/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php):

```
$url = "http://www.example.com/";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
if (strpos($html, "http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41UQmT7-XyL.jpg") !== false) {
  // found
} else {
  // not found
}
```

Comment: How do I download the html to put in the variable?

Comment: `$html = file_get_contents($url)`

Comment: Weird, getting this error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IF in...`

Comment: You have probably missed a semi-colon or a closing bracket off the line before the line number in the error message...

Comment: Yes I did.  Now I'm getting `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')' `.  Doesn't look like I'm missing a closing parentheses, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know if a particular string is present or not, use [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos):

```
if (strpos($html_goes_here, 'http://ecx.blahblah.jpg') !== FALSE)) {
   ... image is present ...
}
```

Note the use of the strict comparison operator, as per the warnings on the linked documentation page.

Answer (score 1):

I mixed params in my comment and you wanted to know how to load the HTML of the URL:

```
$url = "http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00519RW1U";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
$found = false !== strpos($html, 'src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41UQmT7-XyL.jpg"');
```

Comment: Missing semi-colon, and why are you executing a url as a system command? ;-)

Comment: Thank you.  However, you really messed up the first line.  Should be in quotes `""` instead of backticks, and missing the semicolon.