# file_get_contents not actually grabbing file? Blank?

Tags: php

Try this sample code I threw together to illustrate a point:

```
<?php 
$url = "http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B003WSNV4E/";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo($html);
?>
```

The amazon homepage works fine using this method (it is echoed in the browser), but this page just doesn't output anything.  Is there a reason for this, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Works fine here... could it be something with your computer? Firewall?

Comment: Darn, stack overflow is messing up my links.  The correct link is here: http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B003WSNV4E/

Comment: Use Firebug's Net tab or HTTPFox to view the browser-server exchange - it's not a simple url - amazon does a redirect.

Comment: @Rampage Both the URL in the question and the updated one in your comment work for me.

Comment: Related Question: [How to search html file for simple string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153704/how-to-search-html-file-for-simple-string/7153836)

Comment: @hakre: How is that related?  That question is about searching html for a string.  Mine is simply to try to get an html file even downloaded.  I actually saw that question and got an idea for something so I started working on it and encountered this problem.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: Does it work through a php file?  Or just by simply visiting the link?  I can't get it to echo in my php.

Comment: @Marc: I've never used those utilities before, so maybe I'm doing it wrong but it only seems to be downloading this page: http://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B003WSNV4E/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new

Comment: @Rampage: It uses that exact link and according to the OP it is solved with the code fragment you posted above.

Comment: @hakre:  Please don't go blind on me.  It's actually a different link (mine is a light bulb, his is some tablet thingie).  Also, it looks like he got his working but mine definitely isn't.  That's why I came here for help.

Comment: @Rampage: Here is another related one, which might help you trouble shooting your problem: [Why doesn't file_get_contents work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724467/why-doesnt-file-get-contents-work/6724479#6724479)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you're misunderstanding your own code.

You made this comment on the question (emphasis mine):

> I've never used those utilities before, so maybe I'm doing it wrong but **it only seems to be downloading this page**: https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B003WSNV4E/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new

This implies to me that an Amazon page is appearing in your browser when you run this code. *This is entirely expected.*

When you try to download `https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003WSNV4E`, you're being redirected to `https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B003WSNV4E/ref=dp_olp_new?ie=UTF8&condition=new` which is the intent of StackOverflow's RADS system.

What happens from there is your code is loading the **raw HTML** into your `$html` variable and *dumping it straight to the browser*. Because you're passing raw HTML to the browser, the browser is interpreting it as such, and it tries (and succeeds) in rendering the page.

If you just want to see the code, but not render it, then you need to convert it into html entities first:

```
echo htmlentities($html);
```

Comment: or do a `header('Content-type: text/plain');`

Comment: @Marc Well sure, if you want to get all fancy with it. ;) Seriously though, you're absolutely right. It would just also cause issues if OP wanted to output any other HTML on his page.

Comment: @AgentConundrum: Thanks for your help.  However, I think you misunderstand me.  The page I'm using is the page that came directly from the URL in my browser.  Stack Overflow changed it (maybe because I'm a new user?) to be something else.  I don't see *any* redirection in my browser using this link:  `http://amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B003WSNV4E`

Comment: @Rampage I'm getting lost here. What does redirection have to do with this? Both the RADS link and the Amazon link you keep posting work fine for me. What are you expecting to happen exactly?

Comment: @Agent: Okay, do you have a live server somewhere you can test this script?  Can you post a screenshot of that script running and displaying ***anything*** other than a blank page?

Comment: @Agent: This is what mine looks like: https://img.skitch.com/20110823-fatribsqiaxfp4rewfpj6disue.png

Comment: @Agent: I really appreciate the time you took to make those.  However, did you see my screenshot?  Why is that happening?

Comment: @Rampage I see your issue now. Odd that I can't repro it here. What is your `error_reporting` set at? Maybe some error messages are being ignored? Try putting `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);` at the top of the script and seeing if any errors pop up.

Comment: @Agent: Nope, doesn't output anything new or any errors.  It's really strange; that's why I just can't figure this out.  I've never had this problem before.

Comment: @Rampage: That's the weirdest thing. I don't know what else I can offer to help you. Sorry.

Comment: Dear me.  Oh well, thank you for your help, I do appreciate it!

Comment: (Removed links since they were on my personal site, and I don't want the clutter.)

Comment: Using `cURL` seemed to solve the issue.  Also, I noticed that using the `www` in front of the domain helped.  Now it's working!  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm just rewarding you for your help.  I hate leaving questions marked as unanswered even if they're answered. ;)