# How can I extract certain HTML tags e.g. <ul> using Regex with preg_match_all in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am new to regular expressions. I want to fetch some data from a web page source. I used
`file_get_contents("url")` to get the page's HTML source. Now I want to capture a portion within some special tags.

I found `preg_match_all()` works for this. Now I want some help to solve my problem and if possible help me to find out how to solve similar problems like this.

In the example below, how would I get the data within the `<ul>`?
(I wish this sample HTML code could be easier for me to understand.)

```
<div class="a_a">qqqqq<span>www</span> </div>
<ul>
<li>
    <div class="a_a"><h3>aaaa</h3> aaaa aaaaa</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="b_b">bbbbb <span class="s-s">bbbb</span> bbbb</div>
</li>
<li>
    <div class="c_c d-d">cccc cccc ccccc</div>
</li>
</ul>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>sdsdf</td>
    <td>hjhjhj</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>yuyuy</td>
    <td>ertre</td>
</tr>   
</table>
```

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Mr. Shankar Damodaran,
Please checkthe answer of Mr. Basti M bellow, I wanted actually this.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Comment: [All things are possible, but not all expedient](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491/471272).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As the comments stated already, it's generally not recommended to parse html with regex. In my opinion, it depends on what exactly you're going to do.

---

If you want to use regex and know, that there are **no nested tags** of the same kind, the most simple pattern for getting everything that's between `<ul>` and closest `</ul>` would be:

```
$pattern = '~<ul>(.*?)</ul>~s';
```

It matches `<ul>` followed by as few characters of any kind as possible to meet `</ul>`. The dot is a [metacharacter](http://www.hscripts.com/tutorials/regular-expression/metacharacter-list.php), that matches any single character except newlines (`\n`). To make it match newlines too, after the ending [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) `~` I put the s-[modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php). The [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` means zero or more times.

By default [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) are [greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html), which means, they eat up as much as possible to be satisfied. A question-mark `?` after the `*` makes them non-greedy (or *lazy*) and match as few characters as possible to meet `</ul>`. As [pattern-delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) I chose the `~` tilde.

```
preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $out);
```

Matches are captured and can be found in the output-variable, that you set for `preg_match` or `preg_match_all`, where `[0]` contains everything, that matches the whole pattern, `[1]` the first captured parenthesized subpattern, ...

---

If your searched tag can contain attributes (e.g. `<ul class="my_list"...`) this extended pattern, would after `<ul` also include `[^>]*` any amount of characters, that are not `>` before meeting `>`

```
$pattern = '~<ul[^>]*>\K.*(?=</ul>)~Uis';
```

Instead of the question-mark, here I use the `U`-[modifier](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php), to make all quantifiers *lazy*. For only getting captured the desired parts, that are `<ul>` inside `</ul>`. `\K` is used to reset beginning of the reported match. Instead of capturing the ending `</ul>` a [lookahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) is used `(?=`, as we neither want that part in the output.

This is basically the same as `'~<ul[^>]*>(.*)</ul>~Uis'` which would capture whole-pattern matches to `[0]` and first parenthesized group to `[1]`.

---

But, if your html **contains nested tags** of same kind, the idea of the following pattern is to catch the **innermost** ones. At each character inside `<ul>`...`</ul>` it checks if there is no opening `<ul`

```
$pattern = '~<ul[^>]*>\K(?:(?!<ul).)*(?=</ul>)~Uis';
```

**Get matches** using `preg_match_all`

```
$html = '<div><ul><li><ul><li>.1.</li></ul>...</li></ul></div>
         <ul><li>.2.</li></ul>';

if(preg_match_all($pattern, $html, $out))
{
  echo "<pre>"; print_r(array_map('htmlspecialchars',$out[0])); echo "</pre>";
} else {

  echo "FAIL";
}
```

Matches between `\K` and `(?=` will be captured to **$out[0]**

- [\K](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-php.html#k) resets beginning of the reported match ([supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543042/3110638) in PHP since 5.2.4)
- the second pattern, when `<ul>` matched, [looks ahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) `(?!...` at each character, if there's no opening `<ul` before meeting `</ul>`, if so starts over until `</ul>` is [ahead](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) `(?=</ul>)`.
- `[^>]*` any amount of characters, that are not `>` (negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html))
- `(?:` starts a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html).

Used [Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php): `Uis` (part after the ending [delimiter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) `~`)

`U` (PCRE_UNGREEDY), `i` (PCRE_CASELESS), `s` (PCRE_DOTALL)

Comment: Hi Basti M,
you gave the actual answer that I wanted. Its perfect and excellent tutorial too. Especially I was confused with the matching of new line (\n).
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Conside using [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/function.strpos) as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7153704/how-to-search-html-file-for-simple-string)

```
$html = "the page's html source";
$first = strpos($html,'<ul>');
$last = strpos($html,'</ul>');

$ul = substr($html,$first,$last-$first); //the html between the <ul></ul>
```

If there are more than 1 pair of `<ul>` tags, then consider using an offset in `strpos` to grab the relevant bits.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Huey.
Actually I am searching for the regular expression using preg_match_all(); not using substr() . That waht is the regex match for <li>
<div class="a_a">

Comment: I know, but as @C0deH4cker [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), using regex on html isn't such a great idea.